# Не запускается программа с двумя классами в одном java-файле

Tags: java, классы

Доброго времени суток. Недавно начал изучать Java по книге "Изучаем Java" и возникла проблемка с классами больше двух в одном файле.

Дошел до объектов, но как-то с ними не вяжется. В книге приводится пример кода, я его ввожу в NetBeans, но программа отказывается запускаться. Да, в начале книге говорилось не использовать IDE, но все же помогите, чем сможете, пожалуйста, я совсем уж зеленый еще.

Вот ошибка: [image: error]
Чего только не пробовал сделать, никак не исправлю.

Вот код:

```
class Movie {
    String title;
    String genre;
    int rating;
    void playIt() {
 }
}
public class MovieTestDrive {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Movie one = new Movie();
        one.title = "Как Прогореть на Акциях";
        one.genre = "Трагедия";
        one.rating = -2;
        Movie two = new Movie();
        two.title = "Потерянные в Офисе";
        two.genre = "Комедия";
        two.rating = 5;
        two.playIt();
        Movie three = new Movie();
        three.title = "Байт-Клуб";
        three.genre = "Трагедия, но в целом веселая";
        three.rating = 127;
    }
}
```

Comment: А в это "чего только ни пробовал" не входило размещение данного кода в файле _MovieTestDrive.java_? Или удаление слова `public`в объявлении класса?

Comment: и не запускается, а не компилируется

Comment: Пробовал и программа скомпилировалась (как заметил gil9red), но ничего не выполняется. Удалял ли public точно не помню, но кажется было.

Answer (score -1):

в 1 файле может быть только 1 "главный" класс, имя должна совпадать с названием файла. Внутри класса могут быть несколько классов

`MovieTestDrive`  должен быть внутри `Movie`

```
class Movie {
    String title;
    String genre;
    int rating;

    void playIt() {
    }

    public static class MovieTestDrive {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Movie one = new Movie();
            one.title = "Как Прогореть на Акциях";
            one.genre = "Трагедия";
            one.rating = -2;
            Movie two = new Movie();
            two.title = "Потерянные в Офисе";
            two.genre = "Комедия";
            two.rating = 5;
            two.playIt();
            Movie three = new Movie();
            three.title = "Байт-Клуб";
            three.genre = "Трагедия, но в целом веселая";
            three.rating = 127;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую

Comment: Кстати, на счет этого. Я не совсем разобрался как размещать класс внутри класса. Не сочтите за наглость, но не могли бы вы мне пояснить это. Просто очень уж хочется разобраться.

Вы просто перенесли фигурную скобку, закрывающую первый класс, в конец кода?

Comment: В одном файле может быть сколько угодна классов, но публичный только один. И его имя должно совпадать с именем файла

Comment: @AntonShchyrov а что вы в конечном счете подразумеваете под "публичный только один"? Внутренний класс вполне может иметь модификатор `public` и быть доступным из других пакетов. Вы всё же про вариант, в котором в одном файле находятся два внешних класса?

Comment: Теперь при компиляции у меня открывается окно с надписью: "Класс movie.Movie не найден в проекте movie"  :(

Comment: @КасботовИдар не видит, потому что сменился путь к классу. исправьте import-ы

Comment: @КасботовИдар зачем вообще вам несколько классов в одном файле? Разнесите их в разные файлы с соответствующими именами и используйте. А [вложенные классы](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html), думаю, стоит изучать не на самом начальном этапе. Или, в крайнем случае, если нужно прямо сейчас, ознакомиться с документацией, ссылку на которую я дал в этом комментарии.

Comment: @Regent внешний класс с модификатором `public`

Comment: Не нужно путать, в одном файле могут находиться несколько классов на одном уровне (без вложенности), но только один из них может иметь модификатор видимости `public` и именно с его названием должно совпадать наименование файла.